# Perl: Splitting a Pipe Character BUG?

Tags: regex, perl, split, pipe

I'm working on making a BED file but I'm having a problem splitting a variable to get the individual id.

Here are the data

```
fam_scz_uktr_eur_omni*UK1090_0_pca|PT-BHLS    chr15    20301669 ...
```

This is my scrip (I escaped!)

```
if( $id =~ m/\|/g){
    @tempID = split "\|", $id;
    $id = pop(@tempID);
}

...

unless($id =~ m/FID.IID/ || $id =~ m/arrayId/ || $id =~ m/sampleId/){
    $orphan{$id}=$line;
}
```

This is the output of the orphan hash

```
KEY    VALUE
S    fam_scz_uktr_eur_omni*UK1090_0_pca|PT-BHLS    chr15    20301669   ....
```

It's returning the last character. What gives!?

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Are you saying that you have a BED BUG?

Answer (score 4):

Try `@tempID = split /\|/, $id;`.  I think the quotes cause \| to just be interpreted as the pipe character, so the regex engine actually sees only the pipe (i.e. alternation), and not the fact that it's escaped.  (I.e. it's matching on empty string or empty string.)

(Alternatively, you could use `"\\|"`, but that just seems unnecessarily complicated.)

Comment: Correct. The first argument to `split` is a regular expression, not a string. If you pass a double-quoted string, it will be interpolated for the double quotes, and interpolated again as a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

While you can escape with backslashes, most regex special characters lose their meaning when used in a character class.  I find this more readable, and its meaning is consistent no matter how many levels of interpretation are present; there's no need to escape the escape for a string delimited with `"` or even if it is passed to a shell prior to use.

This expression splits the string using such a character class:

```
@tempID = split ("[|]", $id);
```